# Parsing chemical formula

Tags: python, parsing

Parsing: Write a function which will take a string representing a chemical species
and return a list of tuples consisting of elements and corresponding subscripts. In
the absence of a subscript, the subscript should be 1. Example: calling your function
with an input of:

`H2SO4`

should return an output of:

`[('H', 2), ('S', 1), ('O', 4)]`

So I'm trying to do a project but I'm not sure how to start it

can anyone help me how to start this?

Comment: This looks like the prompt of a homework question, which is not what StackOverflow should be used for. At very least, you should state what you've tried and what the problem is.

Answer (score 10):

The following takes you 90% of the way:

```
In [6]: re.findall(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)(\d*)', 'H2SO4')
Out[6]: [('H', '2'), ('S', ''), ('O', '4')]
```

The remaining 10% are left as an exercise for the reader (after all, this is homework).

Hint: a simple list comprehension can do the rest.

Comment: Heh, gotta love Python making things ridiculously easy.  But hopefully this assignment was not about working through algorithms and learning string parsing.

Comment: Good luck with the other 42%!